# How to display the HTML of an image

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Say I have an image like this:

```
<img src="someimage.png" alt="Image" />
```

I want to display the html of that image in for example a code tag, but how can I get it? I can get the image easily:

```
$('img');
```

But how can I get the HTML of it and append it to a code tag?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Say you have an element like this:

```
<code id="mycode"></code>
```

You can do it like this:

```
$("#mycode").append($("<div />").append($('img').clone()).html());
```

Or if you want it semi-encoded for display, like this:

```
var html = $("<div />").append($('img').clone()).html();
$("#mycode").append(html.replace('<','&lt;').replace('>','&gt'));​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​
```

[You can give that a try here](http://jsfiddle.net/nick_craver/amdup/).  The getting the html portion itself is available in plugin form as well, [here](http://dbj.org/dbj/?p=91) and [here](http://github.com/brandonaaron/jquery-outerhtml/blob/master/jquery.outerhtml.js), the encoding, if you need it, you'll have to do yourself, or get a syntax plugin.

Comment: Why are you wrapping the <img/ in the div? It seems like he's trying to just output the html and append it to the codetag.

Comment: @Stefan - `.html()` gets the *innerHTML*, of which there is none :)

Comment: Ah, you needed a parent to make the html content be of the element itself. This seems like a hack workaround that should exist in plugin form.

Comment: @Stefan - There are plugins that do *exactly* this :) Search for `outerHTML` if you want it in plugin form...and I agree if you're using it more than once, go that route.

Comment: In my opinion this should be in the core, but I guess others don't agree since it's not there already.

Answer (score 0):

Plugin form:

```
jQuery.fn.outerHtml = function() {
    return $('<div>').append( this.clone() ).html();
};

$('#mycode').append($('img').outerHtml());
```

Comment: Yes, that gives me nothing because the `html` function returns the inner html, which of course is nothing for an `img`.

Comment: Updated to phrase Nick's answer in plugin form, so it's re-usable.

Comment: @Stefan - The plugin form exists many places, no need to replicate it, and `$(this)` is redundant if you must do it :)

Comment: @Nick Craver: I task you with re-reading the founding purpose of stack overflow. Just because it's on expert-sexchange doesn't mean it shouldn't be here.

Comment: @Stefan - I agree, though this is *many* places on the web was more my point.  My other was just saying if you're posting a plugin as an example, have it as correct as possible :) `$(this)` is cloning the jQuery object as well, just `this.clone()` is much more efficient/less wasteful :)

Comment: Ah, you could have edited my post to make it more correct. I've updated my answer. Who knows, $(this) vs this in a tight inner loop might cause IE to stop responding due to an excess of operations. I've seen weirder things.